# Difference between byte[] and byte ... in Java Methods

Tags: java, methods, arrays

Someone asked me what the difference between the two method parameters and why you would use the ... over specifically assigned array.

```
putMessage(byte ...send)

putMessage(byte[] send)
```

I couldn't answer them with confidence and couldn't remember what the ... is called.

Comment: Thanks all...all great answers too bad i can't split the answered flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is with [Varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

In short

A. First can be used to call with single  byte type arg, 2 byte args.. or many args or an array.

B. second will be used with array only.

Comment: I wonder what the memory usage differences are if you are passing an array?

Answer (score 6):

The `...` in your first example are called [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). Your second example has an array argument. Varargs are a convenience for times when you want to hard code a variable number of arguments to a method but don't want to manually create an array to hold them. It's a shorthand notation. Consider this:

```
putMessage(0b00100101, 0b00100101, 0b00100101); // varargs
```

vs. this:

```
putMessage(new byte[] { 0b00100101, 0b00100101, 0b00100101 }); // array
```

The first example is less cluttered and more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters with ellipses are generally referred to as "varargs" if you want to google that.

Using varargs allows you to call a method with variable number of arguments without having to specify an array e.g.

```
public void printStr(String ...strings) {
    for (String s : strings) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

> printStr("Hello", "World")
Hello
World
```

So varargs allow a certain degree of convenience, but there are downsides - the varargs parameter must be the last parameter in the method signature, and thus you cannot have more than one varargs parameter to a method. If you want to pass multiple arrays to a method you have to use arrays, not varargs.

Another reason you might see arrays in some places where you might expect varargs is that varargs were only introduced in Java 5 - older code and code that needs to be backwards compatible will still be using arrays even where it might make more sense conceptually to use varargs.

The advantage of using varargs in the method signature is flexibility - there are some situations where the caller will have an array ready anyway and some where they will just have several arguments. Varargs will accept either the array or each variable as a separate argument, saving the caller the trouble of instantiating and populating an array.

Answer (score 1):

The ellipsis (three dots) indicates that you are using "varargs".

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html for more details.

Inside the method, you access the elements of "send" as an array.  The two methods are the same in that regard.  The convenience is for the caller.  In the second putMessage, the caller is compelled to create an array of bytes to pass to putMessage.  In the first putMessage, the caller can simply say "putMessage(byte1, byte2)" or "putMessage(byte1, byte2, byte3)" or "putMessage(byte1)" -- variable number of arguments, or varargs.

Answer (score 0):

The ellipses (...) allow you to inline N parameters of a type to a function call without having to define an array first. In the end you do simply get an array of parameters but it's basically shorthand or syntactic sugar. Also your client code might be a little cleaner and more declarative with the ellipses syntax... though it could easily go the other way and become mucky and unreadable.

Here's [a great example](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060106/VariableLengthArgumentLists.html) of the ellipses syntax (variable length argument lists.) While looking at the sample consider what the client code (in the main function) would look like if an array was used instead of a variable length argument list.