# What is the difference between byte and byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, binary, byte

What is the difference between byte and byte array?

```
byte[] array1 ={1,0,0,0}
```

Does this means that the array `1` is having byte value of 1000?

How can I differentiate when to use byte and byte array?

Comment: Do you read it's documentation first? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte?view=netcore-3.1 I think it's quite understandable.  "Array" means it can contins multiple of it. Like `an apple` and  `apples`.

Comment: maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637893/difference-between-byte-and-byte-in-java-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `byte` is (in the case of c#) an unsigned integer composed of 8 bits, so: an integer in the range [0,255]; a `byte[]` is a fixed size chunk of `byte` values, in this case 4 values, with initial values (sequentially) one, zero, zero, zero. This is *not* the same as a value of 1000 - it is 4 discreet values. You could *coerce* a `byte[]` payload to an integer, but what value that *means* is ambiguous:

- we could treat it as a raw big-endian 32-bit integer
- we could treat it as a raw little-endian 32-bit integer
- we could treat the 4 elements as decimal digits
- we could treat the 4 elements as ASCII characters that *might represent* decimal digits

  - or the same with a non-ASCII encoding, for example UTF-16 (big or little endian), UTF-32, etc
- etc

As for when to use each: are you talking about one value, or multiple values? note that `byte[]` is typically used when talking about binary payloads such as file/network contents, although you *can* use `byte[]` for more specific scenarios unrelated to this.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a bit too deep answer for such a question.

Answer (score 0):

byte is a variable that will be between 0 and 255 . byte array is an array that contains byte values ( value 0 to 255)

Comment: byte is *not* a value that will be 0 or 1; that's a *bit*

Comment: 1 byte = 8 bit , and one bit is 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

An array is a structure containing **multiple** values of the same type. A byte array therefore contains multiple bytes. Your array four bytes. The first one is 1, second one 0, third one 0, and so on. The array does have a value of {1,0,0,0}, or [1,0,0,0], and when you call its `ToString()` method, you get `"System.Byte[]"`.